# そういう全てを含めて包み込む度量

Tags: verbs

> A「俺達の戦はもう終わったんだよ。それをいつまでもネチネチネチネチ京都の女かお前は」
> *Our fight has already ended. Stop being so persistent about it, what are you, a Kyoto girl?*
> B「バカか貴様は！京女だけでなく女子はみんなネチネチしている。**そういう全てを含めて包み込む度量がないから**貴様はモテないんだ」
> *Are you stupid? It's not only Kyoto girls that are persistent, every girl is like that. Precisely because you don't have the capacity to ??? you're not popular with them.*

A scene between two former friends who are now busting each other's balls. The bolded part is what I don't understand at all. I kind of managed to narrow down the meaning of 包み込む here to what I **think** is another way to express 受け入れる but even then I really have no clue what that line is trying to get across. Is person B saying that because person A is singling out 京都の女 from all the others, he's unpopular? That doesn't make much sense to me.

よろしくお願いします！

Edit:

This line follows soon after when the person saying it wants to take over control of the situation (she's depicted as a Chinese person and often speaks broken Japanese):

> 善行でも悪行でもやるからには大将やるのが私のモットーよ
> *No matter if good deed or bad deed, I'll be the boss is what I always say.*

^ is what I assume is being said but I'm not sure, the structure throws me off, especially やるからには - I know that からには means ～だから、当然～だ as in
仕事を引き受けたからにはやり遂げないといけない。
*Now that I've taken on the job, I'll have to see it through to the end.*
but it seems kind of out of context in the sentence given above. I've found a source where やるからには is translated as *If I do..., then...* but is that a viable way to use this structure?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this 包み込む can be translated as "to accept" (although there may be a better verb...maybe "embrace"?). 度量 refers to the "capacity" or "breadth" of one's mind. For example, a 度量の大きい(or 広い)人間 is a broad-minded person who is tolerant of many things. そういう全て refers to all the negative traits every girl has (in B's opinion) including ネチネチさ ("persistence", "unforgiveness").

> そういう全てを含めて包み込む度量がないから貴様はモテないんだ。
> You are unpopular with girls because you don't have enough mental capacity to accept everything (including the persistence of girls).

---

からには is a common construction, so please see [this](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF-kara-niwa-meaning/). <del>But 大将やる makes no sense to me. It should be a typo or a reflection of her broken Japanese (I don't know if 大将 means something in a context like this in Chinese).</del>

Comment: 神楽ちゃんは、「ヅラ、ボスなら私に任せるヨロシ。善行でも悪行でも、やるからには大将やるのが私のモットーよ」って、自分が大将をやる（大将になる）って言ったみたいです。

Comment: 「大将」はふつうに使いませんか…？ https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A4%A7%E5%B0%86/ 「５ 一つの集団の中のかしら。「お山の大将」」

Comment: あ、「ボス役をやる」ってことですね、何故か気付いてませんでした…

Comment: naruto, １つ目の質問はありがとうございます、なんとか分かった気がします（が、やっぱり変な言い方だなぁとは思います）。でも大将のやつは未だにピンと来ません。僕の提供した英訳で合ってますか。からにはの文法は分かっているつもりなんですが、この文じゃどうも迷っています…

Comment: @Boolicious I guess you're right...there is an implied object 女子(を), and そういう全てを含めて is an adverbial phrase. A more literal translation would be "have no capacity to accept a girl along with all such faults".

Comment: The last sentence roughly means "Whatever it is, if I do something, it's my policy to do it as a leader" or "Whether it's good or bad, now that we've decided to do this, I will be the boss, and it's my policy."